# How to align boxes horizontal in CSS flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to align my boxes horizontally, but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Each time I try to, they become stacked horizontally. Rather than centered straight across. Or will just remain stacked in a column(vertically).

**HTML for box divs:**

```
<div class="section2">
  <h1 class="s2h1">This is Random Info</h1>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="b1container">
        <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
      </div>
      <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="b1container">
          <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
        </div>
        <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">Placeholder Text</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for box div**

```
.b1container {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #ffdeab;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
}

.b1container:hover {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
}

.s2boxImg {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 3px dotted #553c2b;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.s2boxImg:hover {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border: 3px dotted #f36dcb;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.boxes {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

[Stacked Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Zf2.png)

I have tried to use flex direction row, I used justify content to make sure everything was centered. I attempted to move the divs around to make sure everything was within the correct div. I also tried to space-evenly the div box itself labeled as "box".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested all `.box` elements a few levels deep inside `.boxes`, that is why they are stacked. Make all `.box` elements direct decendants of `.boxes` and it will work.

The *flexbox mechanism* only work one level deep: a **parent flexbox container element** (`.boxes`) contains **flexed child elements** (`.box`). Any element inside a `.box` is unaffected, or better, unhandled by the *flexbox mechanism*. That is why the main structure in your case should be:

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I also added `flex-flow: row wrap` to make `.box` elements wrap to the next line when required.

```css
.b1container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffdeab;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b1container:hover {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.s2boxImg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px dotted #553c2b;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.s2boxImg:hover {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 3px dotted #f36dcb;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* ADDED to make content wrap */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2">
    <h1 class="s2h1">This is Random Info</h1>
    <div class="boxes">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="b1container">
                <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
            </div>
            <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="b1container">
                <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
            </div>
            <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="b1container">
                <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
            </div>
            <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="b1container">
                <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg">
            </div>
            <h5 class="b1Info">Placeholder Text</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this mean that, the way the HTML was structured that it was causing the issue of the stacked boxes (asking for clarification)? Meaning, I nested my div(.box) improperly? Also, is there a way to write more cleaner and readable code as you have? I have the extension prettier, but was wondering if you have any "best practices" tips for future reference?

Comment: Updated the answer. I have my HTML/CSS editor set to automatically add 4 space per code nesting level (not a 'tab' character as you often see in IDE's). I'd say, use a proper code editor with HTML/CSS/JS/SASS, etc. language support. Many dev's use *VSCode* which is free. Take special care of your code readability as it will help you a lot when quickly glancing over code to find bugs or make changes. Use space lines and comment when comment is required, or like I often do, when you are writing a (mini) tutorial. Been doing this for 40+ years and still can understand all my code, any language.

Comment: When you're a solitary developer like me, find (or copy) a style of coding that best fits your needs and stick to it. It is most convenient to read or modify old code without having to figure out wtf you were doing when you first created it. Dive into popular frameworks, they have a 'style' you can adopt. IT is meant to make life easier, why not start with your code/design/text/graphics/thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I am currently using VSCode. I will see if I can add that in my editor settings to automatically add 4 spaces per code nesting level, or any extensions that does this as well. I am ready to dive into popular frameworks, I am doing this project (a simple landing page) in order to understand the basics of HTML/CSS and etc.

Comment: One last thing: Always find the tools that fit your needs, never adjust your needs to fit the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS rule:

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

You're making the div **boxes** flex, but the div which really contains the boxes is the **box** div.

Answer (score 0):

just add the `flex-direction` which take either `row` or `column`

```
b1container {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction :row;
background-color: #ffdeab;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

here is a link that explains flexbox really well
[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

If you don't want the items to wrap when the width gets smaller you could use `flex-wrap`

which you can give `nowrap` attripute `flex-wrap:nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

the .box is not flex, and is he that is holding the boxes
try this:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

this code will put your boxes aligned

if you want to do add a prefix size to each box you can try:

```
.box > * {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

with this you can set the box class to wrap, and you have 4 columns per row.

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS styling is correct. However, the HTML is structured incorrectly. It is logical that the `div.boxes` include a bunch of `div.box`. And each `div.box` has box contents; like in your case `div.b1container` and an `h5` tag. You, however, have nested `div.box` inside `div.box` instead of `div.boxes`.

Here's a figure of how it should be structured:

[image]

Here's the corrected HTML file:

```html
    <div class="section2">
      <h1 class="s2h1">This is Random Info</h1>
      <div class="boxes">        
        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg" />
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg" />
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg" />
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">PlaceHolder Text</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <div class="b1container">
            <img src="" alt="Placeholder" class="s2boxImg" />
          </div>
          <h5 class="b1Info">Placeholder Text</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice little diagram! What tool did you use to create it?

Comment: This was very informative! I believe this happened as I was copying and pasting my div.box instead of typing it out. Also, your example shows how important it is to structure the HTML properly, which provides better readability, and explains why I was not able to catch this error at first glance.